# How do I prevent accidental [Caps Lock] hits, by enforcing a mandatory hold delay of a second or more?

Tags: windows, capslock

Is there a way/utility to activate CAPS LOCK only after the key has been held down for one second or more? I don't want to completely disable it, just prevent accidental activation of this function.

Can AutoHotkey be scripted to do this?

Comment: This will be OS dependent, so please add an OS tag.

Comment: That would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 3):

This can indeed be done with an AHK timer-script. This script will register when Caps Lock is pressed and intercept *Capslock Up*, allowing it to fire only if a certain number of milliseconds has passed. The default timeout is 0.2 sec, this can be configured in the system tray.

```
; AutoHotKey - Suppress CapsLock
; This is a modified version of a scrpt by Lexikos, taken from:
; http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/82509-software-fix-for-double-clicking-mouse/

RegRead minDelay, HKCU, Software\LongCapsLock, MinDelay
if ErrorLevel
    minDelay := 200  ; Default setting.

#NoTrayIcon  ; Hide initial icon.
Menu Tray, Icon, %A_WinDir%\System32\main.cpl  ; Set icon.
Menu Tray, Icon  ; Show icon.
Menu Tray, NoStandard
Menu Tray, Add, &Configure, TrayConfigure
Menu Tray, Add, E&xit, TrayExit
Menu Tray, Default, &Configure
Menu Tray, Click, 1  ; Single-click to configure.
Menu Tray, Tip, Long CapsLock

global _starttime
global timing := 0

CapsLock::
if (timing = 0) {
    timing := 1
    _startTime := A_TickCount
}
return

CapsLock Up::
if (timing = 1) {
    _timeDiff := A_TickCount - _startTime
    ;MsgBox  diff: %_timeDiff%
    if (_timeDiff > minDelay) {
        Send {CapsLock down} 
    }
    timing := 0
}
return

TrayConfigure:
prompt := "Enter minimum duration needed to hold Caps Lock`n"
            . "before it is toggled. The unit is milliseconds."
Loop {
    InputBox newMinDelay, Long CapsLock, %prompt%,,,,,,,, %minDelay%
    if ErrorLevel  ; Cancelled?
        return
    if (newMinDelay+0 >= 150 && newMinDelay <= 10000) ; Valid?
        break
    if (A_Index = 1)
        prompt .= "`n`nPlease enter a number between 150 and 10000."
}
minDelay := newMinDelay
if (minDelay = 200)
    RegDelete HKCU, Software\LongCapsLock
else
    RegWrite REG_DWORD, HKCU, Software\LongCapsLock, MinDelay, %minDelay%
return

TrayExit:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got two AHK scripts here. If you want me to explain further than what I've commented in the scripts, please add a comment below.

The first one is more complex and probably prone to failure, but it sends CapsLock as a literal keypress after holding for one second.

The second one toggles the state of "Caps Lock", which may not be desirable if the reason you want the delay is for some other program's CapsLock hotkey.

You can configure the delay by changing the `Delay` variable in the second line.

---

#### Sends a literal "CapsLock" keypress

```
; Time to wait in milliseconds
Delay = 1000

; Variable used to ignore key repeats
; (Windows sends them when a key is held down)...
CapsLockHeld = 0

; This starts the timer on key *down*.
; Time is measured in milliseconds.
; Timer resolution should be approximately 20 ms.
; The negative time means run only once.
; It will reset the timer if it is already running.
CapsLock::CapsLockDown()

; This stops the timer on key *up*.
CapsLock Up::CapsLockUp()

; This sends a CapsLock keypress when the timer runs out.
SendCapsLock:
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, Off
    HotKey, CapsLock, Off
    HotKey, CapsLock Up, Off
    SendInput, {CapsLock}
    HotKey, CapsLock Up, On
    HotKey, CapsLock, On
Return

; Using functions because otherwise global variables die
CapsLockDown() {
    global CapsLockHeld
    global Delay
    If (CapsLockHeld == 1) {
        Return
    }
    CapsLockHeld = 1
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, %Delay%
    Return
}

CapsLockUp() {
    global CapsLockHeld
    CapsLockHeld = 0
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, Off
    Return
}
```

---

#### Toggles "Caps Lock" state:

```
; Time to wait in milliseconds
Delay = 1000

; Variable used to ignore key repeats
; (Windows sends them when a key is held down)...
CapsLockHeld = 0

; This starts the timer on key *down*.
; Time is measured in milliseconds.
; Timer resolution should be approximately 20 ms.
; The negative time means run only once.
; It will reset the timer if it is already running.
CapsLock::CapsLockDown()

; This stops the timer on key *up*.
CapsLock Up::CapsLockUp()

; This sends a CapsLock keypress when the timer runs out.
SendCapsLock:
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, Off
    If (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T"))
        SetCapsLockState, Off
    Else
        SetCapsLockState, On
Return

; Using functions because otherwise global variables die
CapsLockDown() {
    global CapsLockHeld
    global Delay
    If (CapsLockHeld == 1) {
        Return
    }
    CapsLockHeld = 1
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, %Delay%
    Return
}

CapsLockUp() {
    global CapsLockHeld
    CapsLockHeld = 0
    SetTimer, SendCapsLock, Off
    Return
}
```

Comment: The second script works exactly as advertised. I altered the "delay" variable to 3000 to increase the press down time to 3 seconds.

Comment: I've hacked your second answer to 1) also contain `+CapsLock::CapsLockDown()`, since I also keep hitting Shift-CapsLock by accident, and your script doesn't delay that, and 2) get rid of the wait to turn CapsLock off, as I just don't see a need for it.  You might add such a third vers., or I can post mine as an answer.  Maybe you should provide two or three answers.

Answer (score 1):

A google search gave me this [link to http://chuchuva.com/software/capslockdelay/](http://chuchuva.com/software/capslockdelay/). The 
[first of the three download links](http://chuchuva.com/prog/capslockdelay.zip) still works.

I don't know about the AutoHotKey script. Maybe google for AutoHotKey and caplock delay.

Comment: -1 Not "great". The current answer is just a link labeled as "link", and the second part is "I don't know, try google".

Answer (score 0):

I find an old utility (it is v1.0, dated Jan 2001) called "Toggler" works best for me, although it occasionally appears to become disabled under Windows 10.
It enables me to add a delay to CapsLock with a SmartShift function to unset the CapsLock if the Shift-key and a letter are pressed. It has many other capabilities which I don't use.

Editor's note:  It looks like the developer, Aestas Software, may no longer be around, and the software doesn't appear to have been updated since 2001.  However, it is still downloadable at http://download.cnet.com/Toggler/3000-2072_4-10054498.html

Answer (score 0):

I posted an AHK script here a while back that seemed like it'd work, but the Caps Lock kept maddeningly getting accidentally activated, even though I'd mapped it and Shift-Caps Lock out.  This one is getting it done.

I got sick of time-dependent solutions using AutoHotKey, but once in a blue moon, I do want to type a lot of caps; so I didn't want to disable it.  No script I made would prevent it from turning on with some mysterious accidental combination (on an early M$ ergo kb), so I decided to map it to a keystroke I never use.  The following remaps it to <Ctrl-Pause/Break>.  That key chord does nothing normally, but turns on with the following script.    You can change the key to trigger CapsLock to anything you like.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#NoTrayIcon
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Disable CapsLock and Shift-CapsLock combinations
CapsLock::
+CapsLock::
+^CapsLock::
^CapsLock::

; Uncomment the following lines to also disable the Left Windows Key
;LWin::
;return

; Define the Ctrl-Pause/Break shortcut
^CtrlBreak::
SetCapsLockState % !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
return
```

I don't expect it to interfere with the normal use of the Pause/Break key (which is just about nothing in Windows).  You can compile it into a compact .exe with AutoHotKey too.  I quickly found that other combinations of Shift, Ctrl and CapsLock would also trigger CapsLock, but after fixing it in the code, and using it a few days, it's functioning flawlessly.  I wasn't sure if disabling the CapsLock key in AHK entirely would also disable the CapsLock state when triggered by another key chord, so I just trapped for these CapsLock-triggering combinations.  I have stopped having false CapsLock triggers, and yet CAPS LOCK is still easy go get ;}